# Подружить шифрование C# и Python3

Tags: c#, python-3.x, шифрование, rsa

**Такой вопрос:**
Пытаюсь подружить шифрование с помощью RSA библиотеку BountyCastle на C# и Crypto на Python3.

**Что сделано:** 
Python3 генерирует PEM-ключи RSA, которые так же использует библиотека C#.
Обе библиотеки умеют кодировать и декодировать собственный текст с помощью этих ключей.

**Проблема такая:**
Обе стороны не понимают зашифрованное сообщение, которые было зашифровано другой стороной (C# не понимает Python3, как и наоборот), но прекрасно декодирует собственный текст закодированный с помощью этих ключей.
Как можно их подружить?

Код на стороне C#:

- [Класс шифровки/дешифровки](https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/ClassEncrypt.cs)
- [Код для передачи информации на Python3](https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/SendDataFromCSharpToPython3)

Код на стороне Python3:

- [Создание ключа, получение информации от C#](https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/Python3.py)

Comment: Для начала приведите код

Comment: Вот код на стороне C#: https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/ClassEncrypt.cs

Вот код на стороне Python3 для создания ключа декодировки:
https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/Python3.py

Вот код: отправки данных с C# на Python https://github.com/ELForcer/RSA_CSharp_Python3/blob/master/SendDataFromCSharpToPython3